# Unable to Update State in SideBar.js After Clicking Button in Layout.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

**`Layout.js`** - This component contains a button that, when clicked, should trigger the sidebar to hide or show.

```
'use client'

import { useRef } from 'react';
import './globals.css'
import Menu from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';


export const metadata = {
  title: 'Audio X',
  description: 'Your favourite music player',
}

const menuIconStyles = {
  fontSize: 30, 
  cursor: 'pointer', 
  marginLeft: 3,
  marginRight: 3
}

export default function RootLayout({ menuBtnRef, children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>

        <header className='w-full flex h-16 dark-background-1'>
          <div className='absolute w-60 h-16 top-0 left-0 flex items-center'>
            <Menu htmlColor="white" sx={menuIconStyles} onClick={() => {menuBtnRef?.current.handleMenuClick()}}/>
            <h1 className='text-white text-3xl font-bold'>Audio X</h1>
          </div>
        </header>

        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

**`SideBar.js`** - This component contains the logic for the sidebar, including the state that controls its visibility.

```
'use client'

import { useState, forwardRef, Ref, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';
import Menu from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';

const menuIconStyles = {
  fontSize: 30, 
  cursor: 'pointer', 
  marginLeft: 3,
  marginRight: 3
}

const SideBar = (props, ref) => {
  const [sideBarVisibility, setSideBarVisibility] = useState(false);

  const f = {
    left: sideBarVisibility ? 0 : -240
  }

  function handleMenuClick() {
    console.log("hello");
    setSideBarVisibility((prevState) => {
      return !prevState
    });
  }

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    handleMenuClick: handleMenuClick
  }), [handleMenuClick]);

  return (
    <nav className="h-screen w-60 dark-background-1 z-100 fixed top-0 duration-300" style={f}>
      <div className='absolute w-60 h-16 top-0 left-0 flex items-center'>
        <Menu htmlColor="white" sx={menuIconStyles} onClick={handleMenuClick} />
        <h1 className='text-white text-3xl font-bold'>Audio X</h1>
      </div>
    </nav >
  );
}

export default forwardRef(SideBar);
```

**`page.js`** - This component is responsible for rendering the main content and includes the **`SideBar`** component.

```
'use client'

import Image from 'next/image';
import SideBar from '@/components/SideBar';
import { useRef } from 'react';

export default function Home() {
  const menuBtnRef = useRef(null);
  return (
    <main className="flex">
      <SideBar ref={menuBtnRef}/>
    </main>
  )
}
```

I'm encountering an issue with updating the state in my **`SideBar.js`** component after clicking a button in **`Layout.js`**. I've attempted to use the **`useImperativeHandle`** hook, but have been unsuccessful so far.

I'm looking for guidance on how to correctly toggle the visibility of the sidebar from the **`handleMenuClick`** function in **`Layout.js`**. Despite using **`useImperativeHandle`**, I haven't been able to achieve the desired behavior.

I aim to achieve a similar behavior to the YouTube web page, where clicking a button toggles the visibility of the sidebar. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the menuBtnRef prop received in layout.js will be undefined as you haven't passed it from anywhere and secondly in next.js, the layout preserves state and doesn't re-render, so you should consider doing this functionality via template.js file and do initialize the ref in template.js file itself as you will not be able to pass it as a prop.

Hope this helps!